# Magnetic needles in elastic media

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

I am studying a system with magnetic needles in a elastic media.

The (two-dimensional) system is composed of $N$ magnetic needles distributed in an elastic matrix with Young's modulus is $E$. The needles can be described as cylinders. The $i$th needle has length $L_i$, diameter $a_i$ and magnetic dipole moment $\mu_i$.

At no external magnetic field (i.e.: $H=0$), the $i$th needle form an angle $\theta_i$ with the x-axis, and the end-point of the $i$th needle are $(x_1,y_1)_i$ and $(x_2,y_2)_i$.

- My first question is:

(1) If there is only one needle in the system, if a uniform external magnetic field $H$ is applied, equating  torques associated to magnetic and elastic forces I get that the equilibrium angle $\theta$ is given by:

$\left | d T_e \right |=r.dF_e = r.E.e.dA=r.E.e.\pi.a.dr\Rightarrow $
$T_e=2.\int_{0}^{L/2}E.e.\pi.a.r\ dr = \frac{E.e.\pi.a.L^2}{4}$

where $e$ is the strain, $T_e$ is the elastic torque, $dA$ is the differential area and $r$ is the distance from the mass centre.

Then:$$\mu H\sin \theta = \frac14(E\pi D L^2)\left[\frac{\theta_ị - \theta} \theta\right] $$

And the mass centre of the needle do not change his position. Is this right?

- My 2nd (and last) question in a little harder:

If a uniform external magnetic field $H$ is applied to the system with $N$ needles, how can I obtain the new equilibrium position of all the needles? (I think that I must consider the interaction between needles).

I can use a computer-simulation approach (if required).

Comment: Why not show a few more steps?

Comment: Hi! I updated my question with more steps for question #1. I have nothing for question #2.